# how to find repeated article in wordpress or in database

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I accidentally put some articles in WordPress which is already there, Now it's hard for me to find out. Is there a easy way to do it?

I don't know too much about database, Can I use phpMyAdmin find out?

Comment: You could just search the site with a little chunk of text that appears in the article you think has been repeated. Unless you're trying to find duplicates of any page, then you'll need something fancier. I forget the WP db structure, but a query like: `SELECT left(content, 30), count(*) cnt FROM posts GROUP BY left(content,30) having cnt > 1` would do it.

Comment: Does the same articles have exactly same title, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the articles have for example exactly the same titles, you can get list of article IDs having the same title with:

```
SELECT post_title, COUNT(post_title), GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ')  
FROM wp_posts
GROUP BY post_title
HAVING ( COUNT(post_title) > 1 );
```

You can modify `post_title` to be any other field that you know to indicate the duplicates.

You can use phpMyAdmin, too, since it has an option to make SQL queries. Once you find duplicate rows, just remember to leave one of them there. ;)